# "paster color" not working in ckan 2.8.3 despite being listed as available

Tags: ckan

I'm new to ckan. The version I'm using is ckan 2.8.3 (stable release), installed on Ubuntu16.04LTS from source. I currently have ckanext-scheming, datastore, datapusher plugins installed.

I wanted to add a new color scheme so I ran the following commands

```
. /usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/activate

cd /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan

paster color "#0066aa"
```

The following is the error I got.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/paster", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 102, in run
    invoke(command, command_name, options, args[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 141, in invoke
    exit_code = runner.run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 236, in run
    result = self.command()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ckan/lib/cli.py", line 1734, in command
    path = os.path.join(path, '..', public, 'base', 'less', 'custom.less')
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 68, in join
    if b.startswith('/'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

I'm not quite sure what the problem is as when I ran `paster`
The command for `color` is listed properly

```
Usage: /usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/paster COMMAND
Usage: paster [paster_options] COMMAND [command_options]
Options:
  --version         show program's version number and exit
  --plugin=PLUGINS  Add a plugin to the list of commands (plugins are Egg
                    specs; will also require() the Egg)
  -h, --help        Show this help message
Commands:
  create            Create the file layout for a Python distribution
  help              Display help
  make-config       Install a package and create a fresh config file/directory
  points            Show information about entry points
  post              Run a request for the described application
  request           Run a request for the described application
  serve             Serve the described application
  setup-app         Setup an application, given a config file
ckan:
  check-po-files    Check po files for common mistakes
  color             Create or remove a color scheme.
  config-tool       Tool for editing options in a CKAN config file
  create-test-data  Create test data in the database.
  datapusher        Perform commands in the datapusher
  dataset           Manage datasets
  datastore         Perform commands to set up the datastore
  db                Perform various tasks on the database.
  front-end-build   Creates and minifies css and JavaScript files
  jobs              Manage background jobs
  less              Compile all root less documents into their CSS counterparts
  minify            Create minified versions of the given Javascript and CSS files.
  notify            Send out modification notifications.
  plugin-info       Provide info on installed plugins.
  profile           Code speed profiler
```

I have also tried running with `paster --plugin=ckan color "#0066aa"` and got the same error.
I tried calling some other commands (like jobs/profile/etc. though I didn't actually run them) and it seemed like ckan can find it without problem.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bug. I came across the same issue. With the latest docker image I get the same issue when i run that command. If you raise a bug on https://github.com/ckan/ckan/issues  that will have a look in to what is causing the issue

```
/usr/local/bin/ckan-paster --plugin=ckan color "#0066aa"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ckan-paster", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 102, in run
    invoke(command, command_name, options, args[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 141, in invoke
    exit_code = runner.run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 236, in run
    result = self.command()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/venv/src/ckan/ckan/lib/cli.py", line 1616, in command
    path = os.path.join(path, '..', public, 'base', 'less', 'custom.less')
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/venv/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 68, in join
    if b.startswith('/'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```